# Highlight selection even when tree is not focused

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

I use simultaneously several TVirtualStringTree on the same form.

If a tree has a selected node, but the focus is currently on another tree, the selection is highlighted with a pale gray color.

Is there a simple way to have the selection of an unfocused TVirtualStringTree highlighted with the usual selction color (blue on my computer) ?

Thanks

Comment: If you do that, how would you be able to see which treeview actually has the focus?

Comment: In my case, I don't care so much : tv2 displays info about tv1's selection. And you still have the focus rect to tell you that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While setting the colours will work, the "correct" method is enabling `TreeOptions` --> `PaintOptions` --> `toPopupMode`

```
toPopupMode  // Paint tree as would it always have the focus (useful for tree combo boxes etc.)
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I found it :
TVirtualStringTree has a "Color" property, with configurable subcolors, such as "UnfocusedSelctionColor" ...

Thanks, StackOverflow, for taking the glue out of my eyes :-)

[Edit] This was a first way I found to change the color of an unfocused selection, which workd, but glob's answer is the best way to do this.